# How to fix gunzip error "has flags 0xd4 -- not supported"

Tags: gzip, gunzip

```
prompt: ~/$ gzip -d myfile.csv.gz
gzip: myfile.csv.gz has flags 0xd4 -- not supported
```

Tried googling to no avail, so thought I'd ask directly here.  The files in question were copied using aws s3 cp command.

What does this error mean and how can I fix it so I can uncompress these files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top three bits of the flag byte are reserved and must be set to zero. In this case the top two of the three are set, so the gzip stream is rejected.

It is possible that the file was corrupted, or that it is not a gzip file in the first place.